# #include <windows.h> causes errors

Tags: c, windows, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use GetTickCount() from the windows.h header file. Right now my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "declarations.h"
#define INPUTBUFFER 400 * 6
#define START_POS "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
#include <windows.h>

void interface() {
.....
.....
}
```

The compiler returns 2 errors:

1. Expected '{' before '(' token (pointing to the '(' after "interface"
2. 2 or more data types in declaration specifiers (pointing to "interface")

When I comment out #include < windows.h >, the interface function works just fine. I don't even have GetTickCount() in my code yet. I checked the gcc path to make sure windows.h is there, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: `#define interface struct` exist in windows headers. so you select bad name for function

Answer (score 1):

As RbMm points out in a comment, the windows headers contain "#define interface struct", so the compiler sees your code as "void struct() { ....}" which is not valid C++

You need to either rename your function (probablly the better option) or add a "#undef interface" before your function.